# How To Properly Sign In A User Using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my app a user can create an account and afterwards sign in.

Everything works as it should but I am curious if I have signed in the user "properly".

What I mean by "properly" is that, before I sign-in the user I to check if the user exists using **dataSnapshot** to get the user's **Unique ID** and then I take them to the home page after they have been authenticated.

**But on Firebase I've seen this:**

> " If a user has signed in successfully you can get their account data at
>   any point with the getCurrentUsermethod."

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

    // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
    // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
    // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
    String uid = user.getUid();
}
```

As you can see in the above code-block in the comments is says to use `FirebaseUser.Token( )`

I am a bit confused if the way I did it was fine or if I have to do it another way using the Token mentioned on Firebase.

**My logic:**

Before I sign in the user I check to see if the user already has an account on Firebase:

```
// Check if the user has already signed up and exists in the database
    private void checkIfUserSignedUp() {

        // Get the currently authenticated user
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        // If user exists
        if (mUser != null) {

            // Retrieve current user's unique id
            final String user_id = mUser.getUid();


            // Listen for changes in database
            mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    // Data snapshot checks contents of the database at the reference. In this case
                    // Checking for registered user by their unique id
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)) {

                        // Take user to the home/main page after successfully signing in
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        // User does not exist in the database. Has not signed up.
                        // Take user to register profile
                        Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                        startActivity(registerIntent);
                        finish();

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // User cancelled task...

                }
            });
        }// End if

        // Hide progress dialog
        mLoginProgress.dismiss();
    }
```

As you can see above in the image I used `dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)` to check for the user's existence.

Is this fine? Or was I supposed to do an alternative way in which I checked for the user using `Firebase.getToken( )`

I just don't want any issues with the app later if my way isn't correct.

**EDIT:**

So I changed my method to the following and the user was able to log in just fine:

```
private void checkIfUserSignedUp() {

        // Get the currently authenticated user
        mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    if (mUser != null) {

                        // Take user to the home/main page after successfully signing in
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        // User does not exist in the database. Has not signed up.
                        // Take user to register profile
                        Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                        startActivity(registerIntent);
                        finish();

                    }
        mLoginProgress.dismiss();

}
```

So basically the code-block at the very top was being done improperly even though it worked.

So since one issue is resolved thanks to those who commented. The next thing is as I had asked previously, what is `Firebase.getToken()` and when is it used?

Comment: Please share the code as text. As entertaining as this picture is, it's not as reusable.

Comment: I do not understand why you are trying to check if a user already signed up by looking up his/her `uid` inside your database, if `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` already tells you if he/she is signed in (and therefore has signed up) or not.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I posted the actual code.

Comment: @hotrod I see. Very new to firebase so I was just experimenting. Thanks for the clarification. Also how exactly does the Firebase.getToken( ) work? I am also curious about this.

Comment: As explained in the answer by Arnis Shaykh you do only need this method if you are going to authenticate users with your own back-end. I guess you are not so you pretty much do not need that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question what is `Firebase.getToken()`

> public Task getToken (boolean forceRefresh) Also:
>   Google Play services
>
> Fetches a Firebase Auth ID Token for the user; useful when
>   authenticating against your own backend. Use our server SDKs or follow
>   the official documentation to securely verify the integrity and
>   validity of this token.

Basically it is a unique identifier for user in your project just like the one that you get with `getUid()`. My guess it is done to avoid compromising your Firebase DB data in case your backend gets hacked.